# How to only enable submit function, when smth in dropdown is slected

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am building a web app and have a question to my drop down menu.
The goal is, that the data can only be submitted, when a number is selected in the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check if the dropdown is set or not should be enough. If the input of the request is invalid, the correct response would be a 400.

```
app.get('/lbc.js', (req, res) => {  
    if (req.body.dropdown === undefined || req.body.dropdown === null)
        
        res.status(400).send({ message: "Drop down was not selected" });
        return;
    }

    // continue with whatever you want if submit is possible
}
```

Your frontend needs to handle this response as well, because now it probably won't make a distinction when it works or not. So if you'd capture the submit event of the form, you could send the request yourself using the `fetch` api, and do different things for a 200 (when the response succeeded) or something like a 400 (request failed).

EDIT:
You can read up on how to create and handle submit events here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event

Here you can read how you can send webrequests through javascript:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

These are the steps you need to do:

- Put an `id` on your form, e.g. `<form id="myForm" ... >`
- Start a JavaScript tag i.e. `<script> </script>`
- Within these tags, first get the form reference:
  `const form = document.findElementById("myForm");`
- Put a submit event listener on it like how they do in the link
- In the event handler function, send the request, and deal with the response (show message if error, do something else if success for instance).

### EDIT april 7th:

About your code and your comments I have the following to say:

- You have created 2 forms, one for your dropdown and one for your button. Both of them should be in the same `<form></form>` tag. When you click your submit button, all `<input>` fields will be sent to whereever your form submits to.
- You seem to need to check if all fields are filled in correctly before you send the data to your server. Like I said in my previous answer, you need to create a script that will do this. In this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event) you can read again in a simple way how to do such a thing
- Checking if a field has a value is again done by obtaining the element through it's `id`. E.g. if you have an input like: `<input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" />`, you can obtain the value of this field in javascript as such: `const valueFromField = document.getElementById("firstName").value;`

Hopefully this will give you some hints to make some new steps.
In my humble opinion it would probably be a good idea for you to do some basic javascript tutorials to give you some insight on how that stuff works.

Comment: Thank you very much @Glubus. I got it. How do I need to edit my frontend, that it can handle the response? I guess '<form method="POST">' is not enough? (Sorry am just started with all this topics ....) - I am very thankful for your support.

Comment: Thank you so much @Glubus ! I do really appreciate your time.  I will try everything out and see (and hope) if I can solve it by myself.

Comment: hey @Glubus  I tried different things out, but I still have some mistakes, that my code doesn't work the way I want it. I updated the code in my question. It would be great if you could have a look at my code to give some further recommendations/hints. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Apologies for not getting back to you Agnes, do you still require help?

Comment: No problem @Glubus , I know you are very busy. Yes, would be great if you could help me, am still on this issue....

Comment: @Agnes I've updated my answer, hopefully this'll help you some more.

Answer (score 1):

According to the given details, Try this.

You can check the value and perform your actions as below.

```
if(req.body && req.body.dropdown) {
    res.send('submit is possible')
} else {
    res.send('Please select the amount!')
}
```

Also use, **POST** method route

```
app.post('/test', function (req, res) {
  res.send('POST request to the homepage')
})
```

Read more about [Express.js routing](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)

Comment: thank you for your help and the link. Can I use the Post method and the if (req.body...) somehow together in the node js file?   And I don't want to write "submit is possible' I like to activate on this position the submit button, but I don't know how to program this. Do you have an idea? - Thank you so much for your help!! (Sorry, for my maybe "stupid" question...am completely a beginner..)

Comment: Let's say you need to save data into database only if dropdown has a value, then above code will work. `res.send('your message here')` will send your message to the place where you make the API call and you can show a notification to the user as **Action processed** or **Please select the amount!**

Comment: @Agnes Follow this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6BozpmSjk-Y). You can get an idea about how Node.js works.

Comment: Thanks @Bishan the Tutorial is really good.